Using JQ how to append entry to dictionary type array in JSON or create it if array doesn't exist?
I have ideal JSON:
{
    "environments":[
        {
            "name":"test",
            "release":"2.0"
        },
        {
            "name":"prod",
            "release":"1.0"
        },
    ]
}

This file could be in any state:

It can be empty file with just empty object { }
It can have empty "environemnts" array
It can have some entries in environment array but not the one we want to update

I need to update or create the "release" tag with given version under given environment.
I tried variations of:
(.environments[] | select(.name == "prod") | .release) = "3.0" // .environments += [{"name": "prod", "release": "3.0"}]

I also tried:
.environments
|=  (map(.name) | index("prod")) as $ix
    | if $ix 
      then .[$ix]["release"] = "2.0" 
      else . + [{name: "release", value: "2.0"}]
      end

But it either fails on empty file. Or doesn't create new entry.
I'm lost here.

Fix your JSON to be syntactically valid. In its current state, it isn't

You can add the new element everywhere and then delete the old prod release if it existed:
jq --arg release 1.2 '.environments += [{"name":"prod","release":$release}]
                      | del(.environments[]
                            | select(.name == "prod" and .release != $release))' file.json

Tested on the following 4 files:
echo '{}' > 1.in
echo '{"environments":[]}' > 2.in
echo '{"environments":[{"name":"test","release":"2.0"}]}' > 3.in
echo '{"environments":[{"name":"test","release":"2.0"},{"name":"prod","release":"1.0"}]}' > 4.in


You could create an INDEX, then update the .prod field. This way, it is either updated if it existed, or created if it didn't. Afterwards, iterate over the items to restore the array. Using the ? operator when creating the stream takes care of the empty object case.
.environments |= [
  INDEX(.[]?; .name) | .prod = {name: "prod", release: "2.0"} | .[]
]

This turns both {} and {"environments": []} into:
{
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "prod",
      "release": "2.0"
    }
  ]
}

And updates the given sample (after removing the abundant comma) into:
{
  "environments": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "release": "2.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "prod",
      "release": "2.0"
    }
  ]
}

Demo

I really like this approach. One more question. How would I go about nesting it?
I mean what if each "environments" array is inside "tenent" object. And on top level there is tenants[] array with those "tenant" objects.

@Hooch Prosaic descriptions of structures are hard to follow, and may easily miss some not-so-unimportant aspects. Maybe you are looking for .tenants[].tenent.environments |= […]? Note the different spellings …nan… and …nen… that I have just copied from your description. In the end, it really depends on what your actual goal is, and what else is in the structure that should not be matched or affected etc.

Like this {
"tenants":[
{
"name": "MyClient32",
"deployments":[
{
"environment":"staging",
"release":"23"
}
]
}
]
}
I try to only update release in Test-staging for example.
I tried nesting those INDEX functions but it never works out to what I need.

Again, in this format it remains pretty unclear what to match (e.g. there is no Test-staging, so I'm starting to guess), and, equally important, what NOT to match (here, with only one item, I'd say just match all). So, please avoid trying to solve new problems in passing. Either provide a full example added to (not replacing!) your current question, or, especially if it is not just a trivial special case of the above, ask a new question. That way you can provide all important details, sample data, a link to a playground even, and attract more people, leading to more approaches and solutions.

Itried this. But it doesn't work:
INDEX(INDEX(.[]?;.name).Test;.environment).staging.release="vv"
The only think is I want to set property "release" of deployment object with "environment" = staging for tenant with name Test. And to create that structure if it doesn't exist.

I also tried "merging" my new release object with current file.
But this just replaces the contents. I probably need to use index here somehow.
. |= .+ {tenants:[{name:"Test", deployments:[{environment:"staging",release:"vNEW"}]}]}
